# excel vs matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, contour

I'm trying to reproduce an excel chart in matplotlib, but the matplotlib version looks truncated.
The excel version plots the entire ellipse but the matplolib version don't.

[image: excelvsmatplotlib]

The excel plot is generated using only the insert chart without any modifications

The first col is the x-axis and the first row is the y-axis, this is why the transposition.

There is any difference between how excel and matplolib "load" the values to the chart?

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df = df.T
x = df.columns.values
y = df.index.values
Z = df.values
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
cp = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
cp = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='k')
```

Regards

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/dhfs1Ah) is the image of the question

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: The data should be identical both the cases, but the default values of the contour levels must be different. You can check what levels are set in Excel and the set the same value for `levels` keyword for the `contourf` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the people that were using excel to plot failed to mention me that they were filtering the data in the plot itself ...

so using the levels parameters in contourf  i was able to replicate the scale in the final plot.

Sorry for the inconvenience

Regards